# Row-Level Security Is this a good way to protect registered registries against other database administrators

Tags: sql-server

Row-Level Security Is this a good way to protect registered registries against other database administrators that do not have enough information or sensitivity to recorded data or misuse of data for personal resources.

I am using Microsoft SQL Server. As you know, edit the data in the database either manually by the original environment using SQL Server user SA or any user of other authorized and also through programming environment that connects to SQL Server to edit the data. 
Is there a way to disable this editing of data in the SQL Server environment so there is no person in the database manually does not change?

[image]

No users even through MSSQL unable to make changes in the original data. For example, to manually stock the number to another number that this event would not have realized how to change.

can SINGLE_USER help?

Can wizard SQL manager for remote did not open?

Who does not have access to SQL server console? And changes only through an interface software or Command Line in the master database server operating system?

Comment: it's impossible, database server always allow changes with proper credentials. although you could simply rules out another user but the user that being used by your app to access the db (just like @Danie Schoeman answer). However, once the credentials within application leaked, someone else can use it to access the db and change it.

Comment: Excuse me, what does "Can wizard sql manager for remote did not open?" mean? And SINGLE_USER doesn't help, this is used only for maintenace tasks and in live environment you most likely stop any access for your database for legitimate clients.

Comment: I think that best way is "database only is edited by sa when connect directly to server and use command for edit database on shell environment and nobody cannot remotely edit it, i means dont connect console "ssms" remotely."

Comment: Why is this question tagged as 'asp.net' ?

Answer (score 2):

Change the password of the SA user and do not give it out.
Do not give user access to the database specific using the dbo, data writer and associates roles.
Only allow users access via the data reader role.
Only admin user (if any) should have data writer access.
Give and specific user utilized via the programming side more elevated permissions.

Comment: Do SINGLE_USER can help?

Can wizard sql manager for remote did not open ?

Comment: Single_USER only allows one user to be connected at any time.

Answer (score 0):

**Row-Level Security** is a nearly good feature in SQL server 2016.

Row-Level Security enables you to implement restrictions on data row access.

> For example ensuring that workers can access only those data rows
>   that are pertinent to their department, or restrict a customer's data
>   access to only the data relevant to their company.

[image]